# Android why after airplane mode off the phone asks for sim's pin code

Tags: android, mode, airplane-mode

As i've read through the internet some phones after the airplane mode ask for the pin code again like when you switch on the phone. 
This has to do with the phone's brand or the version of android?
Is there a way to bypass that through settings for example?

And how can i programmatically can auto provide my pin to device (i mean saving my pin in a phone's app so when i turn off the airplane mode the device wont ask me for my pin but it will retieve it from the app) and the phone will return back to normal!

Sorry for my english but i've been trying to find that out but no help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concerning the PIN request it certainly is related to the phone's modem and how it enters and exits Airplane mode power-wise. Some devices do it "gracefully" (PIN only at bootup) and others need it after airplane mode.

For the programmatic aspect I do not have an answer, I don't think it's possible. Why not disable the PIN altogether, and optionally put a good password to unlock your phone instead? These days the phone is worth more than the sim card, which can be easily disabled.